# How to get models with related models in Zend Framework 2? (relations)

Tags: php, zend-framework, join, orm, zend-framework2

I have models `Message` and `File`. Message can have a lot of files (attachments).

I need to do something like:

```
new Select('message')->join('file', 'file.message_id = message.id', array('url'), 'left')
```

but I want to get `Message` array where every message has a property `files` with an array of `File`. How to do something like this in zf2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zf2 does not implement any ORM from the beginning, it's using Gateway pattern, you give it a request, it returns a ResultSet which is iterable, and return a ResultSetPrototype (object) or an Array for each row in the ResultSet.

If you want an ORM, you'll have to build it or use one like Doctrine 2 (which has an implementation on Zf2)

resources :

- [ZF2 - Doctrine2 quick tuto](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial)
- [official github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)
- [Another tuto](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/)